# Error:cannot recognize input near 'minus' 'SELECT' '*' in table source while running in spark-sql

Tags: hive, apache-spark-sql

Can anyone tell me how to resolve the below issue in `spark-sql`.

```
SELECT * FROM encrypted_im.abc
MINUS
SELECT * FROM encrypted_im.abc;
```

> **Error:cannot recognize input near 'minus' 'SELECT' '*' in table source
>   SELECT store_num,store_nm FROM encrypted_im.base_abc
>   minus
>   SELECT store_num,store_nm FROM encrypted_im.base_abc;
>   Error:cannot recognize input near 'minus' 'SELECT' 'store_num' in table source;**

Answer (score 0):

Could you try `EXCEPT` instead of `MINUS` as following:

```
SELECT * FROM encrypted_im.abc 
EXCEPT
SELECT * FROM encrypted_im.abc;
```

I think that `MINUS` doesn't exist in SparkSql, SparkSql generally follows Hive style, so you can refer to Hive Syntax. [here](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/sql-programming-guide.html#compatibility-with-apache-hive) the supported and unsupported Hive features by SparkSql.